# Facelet was modified messages

Tags: jsf, richfaces, seam, facelets

I see this information in my jboss console, when my pages don't render properly. Does anyone know what this means?

```
14:22:46,403 INFO  [facelet] Facelet[/layout/header.xhtml] was modified @ 1
:54:54 PM, flushing component applied @ 2:22:43 PM
14:22:46,404 INFO  [facelet] Facelet[/layout/header.xhtml] was modified @ 1
:54:54 PM, flushing component applied @ 2:22:43 PM
14:22:46,405 INFO  [facelet] Facelet[/layout/header.xhtml] was modified @ 1
:54:54 PM, flushing component applied @ 2:22:43 PM
14:22:46,406 INFO  [facelet] Facelet[/layout/header.xhtml] was modified @ 1
:54:54 PM, flushing component applied @ 2:22:43 PM
14:22:46,406 INFO  [facelet] Facelet[/layout/header.xhtml] was modified @ 1
:54:54 PM, flushing component applied @ 2:22:43 PM
14:22:46,407 INFO  [facelet] Facelet[/layout/header.xhtml] was modified @ 1
:54:54 PM, flushing component applied @ 2:22:43 PM
14:22:46,408 INFO  [facelet] Facelet[/layout/header.xhtml] was modified @ 1
:54:54 PM, flushing component applied @ 2:22:43 PM
14:22:46,409 INFO  [facelet] Facelet[/layout/header.xhtml] was modified @ 1
:54:54 PM, flushing component applied @ 2:22:43 PM
14:22:46,411 INFO  [facelet] Facelet[/layout/header.xhtml] was modified @ 1
:54:54 PM, flushing component applied @ 2:22:43 PM
14:22:46,412 INFO  [facelet] Facelet[/layout/header.xhtml] was modified @ 1
:54:54 PM, flushing component applied @ 2:22:43 PM
14:22:46,413 INFO  [facelet] Facelet[/layout/header.xhtml] was modified @ 1
:54:54 PM, flushing component applied @ 2:22:43 PM
14:22:46,414 INFO  [facelet] Facelet[/layout/content.xhtml] was modified @
1:54:54 PM, flushing component applied @ 2:22:43 PM
14:22:46,415 INFO  [facelet] Facelet[/layout/content.xhtml] was modified @
1:54:54 PM, flushing component applied @ 2:22:43 PM
14:22:46,417 INFO  [facelet] Facelet[/layout/content.xhtml] was modified @
1:54:54 PM, flushing component applied @ 2:22:43 PM
14:22:46,425 INFO  [facelet] Facelet[/layout/content.xhtml] was modified @
1:54:54 PM, flushing component applied @ 2:22:43 PM
14:22:46,426 INFO  [facelet] Facelet[/layout/content.xhtml] was modified @
1:54:54 PM, flushing component applied @ 2:22:43 PM
14:22:46,428 INFO  [facelet] Facelet[/layout/content.xhtml] was modified @
1:54:54 PM, flushing component applied @ 2:22:43 PM
14:22:46,429 INFO  [facelet] Facelet[/layout/content.xhtml] was modified @
1:54:54 PM, flushing component applied @ 2:22:43 PM
14:22:46,430 INFO  [facelet] Facelet[/layout/content.xhtml] was modified @
1:54:54 PM, flushing component applied @ 2:22:43 PM
14:22:46,431 INFO  [facelet] Facelet[/layout/content.xhtml] was modified @
1:54:54 PM, flushing component applied @ 2:22:43 PM
14:22:46,432 INFO  [facelet] Facelet[/layout/content.xhtml] was modified @
1:54:54 PM, flushing component applied @ 2:22:43 PM
14:22:46,432 INFO  [facelet] Facelet[/layout/content.xhtml] was modified @
1:54:54 PM, flushing component applied @ 2:22:43 PM
14:22:46,433 INFO  [facelet] Facelet[/layout/content.xhtml] was modified @
1:54:54 PM, flushing component applied @ 2:22:43 PM
14:22:46,434 INFO  [facelet] Facelet[/layout/content.xhtml] was modified @
1:54:54 PM, flushing component applied @ 2:22:43 PM
14:22:46,434 INFO  [facelet] Facelet[/layout/content.xhtml] was modified @
1:54:54 PM, flushing component applied @ 2:22:43 PM
14:22:46,435 INFO  [facelet] Facelet[/layout/content.xhtml] was modified @
1:54:54 PM, flushing component applied @ 2:22:43 PM
14:22:46,436 INFO  [facelet] Facelet[/layout/content.xhtml] was modified @
1:54:54 PM, flushing component applied @ 2:22:43 PM
14:22:46,437 INFO  [facelet] Facelet[/layout/content.xhtml] was modified @
1:54:54 PM, flushing component applied @ 2:22:43 PM
14:22:46,438 INFO  [facelet] Facelet[/layout/content.xhtml] was modified @
1:54:54 PM, flushing component applied @ 2:22:43 PM
14:22:46,438 INFO  [facelet] Facelet[/layout/content.xhtml] was modified @
1:54:54 PM, flushing component applied @ 2:22:43 PM
14:22:46,439 INFO  [facelet] Facelet[/layout/content.xhtml] was modified @
1:54:54 PM, flushing component applied @ 2:22:43 PM
14:22:46,440 INFO  [facelet] Facelet[/layout/content.xhtml] was modified @
1:54:54 PM, flushing component applied @ 2:22:43 PM
14:22:46,441 INFO  [facelet] Facelet[/layout/content.xhtml] was modified @
1:54:54 PM, flushing component applied @ 2:22:43 PM
14:22:46,442 INFO  [facelet] Facelet[/layout/content.xhtml] was modified @
1:54:54 PM, flushing component applied @ 2:22:43 PM
14:22:46,443 INFO  [facelet] Facelet[/layout/content.xhtml] was modified @
1:54:54 PM, flushing component applied @ 2:22:43 PM
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's an error of Facelets, fixed in the new release. Which version of facelets are you using?

[Here's some info](http://old.nabble.com/Error%3a-Facelet-was-modified,-flushing-component-applied-tc13500808.html)

[Facelet Bugtracker](https://facelets.dev.java.net/issues/show_bug.cgi?id=336)

Comment: I am using facelets version 1.1.15.B1 along with Seam 2.2. Not sure what is the compatible newer version of facelets with Seam 2.2 though.

Comment: Just check it in the MANIFEST file of the facelets jar

Answer (score 21):

When deploying a new `EAR` or `war` created from a machine with time settings different from that of the server where application is deployed, flushing of the `JSF` components can happen.

Logs will show the following error.

The reason being, when ever a new request is made, server sees the page as modifed in future time stamp and starts compiling again. This causes the component tree to be created again, causing to lose all the state stored by the component.

To fix this add `facelets.REFRESH_PERIOD` to the `web.xml`

`REFRESH_PERIOD` indicates, When a page is requested, what interval in seconds should the compiler check for changes. If you don't want the compiler to check for changes once the page is compiled, then use a value of `-1`. Setting a low refresh period helps during development to be able to edit pages in a running application.

`web.xml`, should look like this,

```
<context-param>
<param-name>facelets.REFRESH_PERIOD</param-name>
<param-value>-1</param-value>
</context-param>
```

`-1`indicates not to check for changes, since production servers it is safe to set this value.