# Why does primefaces return message for ID that doesnt exist

Tags: ajax, primefaces, jsf-2.2

I'm writing a JSF application with primefaces which uses bean validation.
I have an input validation message being returned on form submission:

```
<partial-response><changes><update id="pageForm:j_idt88"><![CDATA[<div id="pageForm:j_idt88" class="ui-messages ui-widget form__error" aria-live="polite"><div class="ui-messages-error ui-corner-all"><span class="ui-messages-error-icon"></span><ul><li role="alert" aria-atomic="true"><span class="ui-messages-error-summary">must be true</span></li></ul></div></div>]]></update><update id="j_id1:javax.faces.ViewState:0"><![CDATA[2771262580625457800:-3174803273303516341]]></update><extension ln="primefaces" type="args">{"validationFailed":true}</extension></changes></partial-response>
```

Yet no element exists within my page with an ID of `pageForm:j_idt88`.
I noted the IDs are sequential and the highest one in the page only reaches `j_idt80`

I've put in `<ui:debug>` to my page and inspected the component tree which corresponds to the HTML. (No element with ID of `pageform:j_idt88`)

The element I believe it should be updating is nested within the (only) `h:form`. Output as :

```
<div id="pageForm:confirm:j_idt75" aria-live="polite" class="form__error ui-message"></div>
```

Where do I start looking to debug why this is happening?

Comment: `ui-messages` is normally rendered by `<p:messages>` not `<p:message>`. So I'd search for `<p:messages[^>]*>` in all XHTML files.

Comment: And you might have `<p:autoUpdate>` on your messages so its trying to update it every AJAX request?

Comment: Yes. I have `<p:messages><p:autoupdate/></p:messages>` in the page however there's no messages displayed in that on the ajax completion

Comment: If it's of relevance. I also see this in the server log: `Facelet[/pages/subscribe.xhtml] was modified @ 11:21:47, flushing component applied @ 11:21:47`. I have tried to rectify that by setting refresh period as per https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3820111/facelet-was-modified-messages

Comment: So you now know which component it is. Give it an ID.